# How to show Output of matrix in FortranForm with "&" character?

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, fortran

I have a matrix. and i have shown the output of matrix one by one element in FortranForm.

the problem is i want to put "&" continuation charater in output because when i am copying the data into fortran Code, Fortran is showing warning that it exceeds 2048 characters .

So i wanted to put ampersand character in each output of matrix element in FortranForm......please help

For example if matrix(1,1)=a1^2+b11^2 (a long line 2048 characters)

then i want it to be shown like matrix(1,1)=a1^2+b11^2 &
                                            & +c^2+.....(breaking each line with '&')

Above expression is in fortranform but could not show here as text

Answer (score 4):

I think you should try to improve your question: it always helps when you provide an example as working code that shows the problem and explain what output you want to achieve for that example. Here is code which I think should do what you have asked for:

```
matrixToFortranForm[mat_?MatrixQ, matName_String, lineLength_: 70] := 
Module[{x, y},
  StringRiffle[
   Flatten@Table[
     StringReplace[
      ToString[
       Row[{
         StringForm["`1`(`2`,`3`) = ", matName, x, y],
         FortranForm[mat[[x, y]]]
         }],
       PageWidth -> lineLength
       ]
      ,
      {StartOfLine ~~ " \n" -> "", "\n" -> "&\n"}
      ],
     {x, Length[mat]},
     {y, Length[First[mat]]}
     ],
   "\n\n"
   ]
  ]
```

to try it you could use:

```
m = Table[Expand[(b + x a)^y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 5, 10}];
matrixToFortranForm[m, "matrix"]
```

Comment: very helpful! thank you @Albert Retey

Answer (score 3):

I also have this problem, and try this code **F90Format**

```
Unprotect[D]; Clear[D]; Protect[D];
NN[exp_] := N[exp, 50];
Unprotect[Real];
RTogle = False;
Real /: Format[r_Real /; r >= 0, FortranForm] /; (RTogle = ! RTogle) :=
   Module[{mantissa, exponent, tmp},
   {mantissa, exponent} = MantissaExponent[r];
   If[r === 0., exponent = 1];
   SequenceForm[10 mantissa, D, exponent - 1]
   ];
Protect[Real];
F90Format[exp_, pre_: ""] := Module[{tmp, sqrt, splits},
   tmp = FortranForm[exp];
   tmp = ToString[tmp, PageWidth -> Infinity, 
     TotalWidth -> Infinity];
   splits = StringSplit[tmp, " "];
   tmp = Fold[If[StringLength[Last@#1] + StringLength[#2] > 100,
       Join[#1, {#2}],
       Join[Most[#1], {StringJoin[Last[#1], #2]}]] &,
     {First@splits}, Rest[splits]];
   tmp = StringJoin @@ Riffle[tmp, " &\n"];
   tmp = pre <> tmp;
   Return[tmp];
   ];
```